# How to play with others?

Tags: simcity-2013

How to do you start a multiplayer game in SimCity.

I have tried creating multiple games that were public, but no one joins the regions.

When I browse `Join Game` from the main menu. All the regions that are shown in the list are full.

Comment: New zones are at the bottom so do 'show more' a bunch of times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Region searching is currently broken!  When it is fixed, the task you are trying to do will be easy.  Until then, the best you can do is invite through the friend system.

Comment: Note to self, region searching may be repaired at this point.  Need to check.